# ReactJs: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to setup rich text box in my content body section, so I like to use `npm react-quill` It's install succesfully then I have used a bubble them form `react-quill` It's also warking succesfully. But when I try to show my post then display like this:

```html
<h1>Hello this </h1><blockquote>is my five no <strong>of post</strong></blockquote>
```

But I need to plain text with rich text editor. Then I have used `npm install react-render-html`.

After that when I try to see my post then show me error like this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
push../node_modules/parse5/lib/tokenizer/preprocessor.js.module.exports.push../node_modules/parse5/lib/tokenizer/preprocessor.js.Preprocessor.write
C:/Users/alami/OneDrive/Desktop/MERN stack/MERN CRUD/frontend/node_modules/parse5/lib/tokenizer/preprocessor.js:91
  88 |     else
  89 |         this.html = chunk;
  90 | 
> 91 |     this.lastCharPos = this.html.length - 1;
  92 |     this.endOfChunkHit = false;
  93 |     this.lastChunkWritten = isLastChunk;
  94 | };
```

I have tried code like this:

```
import renderHtml from "react-render-html";

  const showSinglePost = () => (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-8 offset-md-2 pt-3 pb-2">
        <h1>{post.title}</h1>
        <div className="lead pt-3">{renderHtml(post.content)}</div>
        <p>
          Author: <strong>{post.user}</strong> Published on{" "}
          <strong>{new Date(post.createdAt).toLocaleString()}</strong>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
  return <div className="container">{post && showSinglePost()}</div>;
};
```

Comment: what is in `this.html` ?

Comment: Hard to suggest anything without seeing more relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution by this way:

```
import renderHtml from "react-render-html";

  const showSinglePost = () => (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-8 offset-md-2 pt-3 pb-2">
        <h1>{post.title}</h1>
        <div className="lead pt-3">{renderHtml(post && post.content)}</div>
        <p>
          Author: <strong>{post.user}</strong> Published on{" "}
          <strong>{new Date(post.createdAt).toLocaleString()}</strong>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
  return <div className="container">{post && showSinglePost()}</div>;
};
```

Just I have to add this line: `{renderHtml(post && post.content)}`

Answer (score 0):

you gotta check in console wheather this.html contains any data,

if yes you can try this
this.html.length
try destructuring it to

const{html}=this

then try html.length